# Sum using a Block

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to pass an rspec and normally I would do a method and pass a function in.
All I have to do is add one, I'm embarrassed I'm even posting here...

normally I would do

```
def adder(n)
   n+1
end
```

However I need to pass in a block and I'm not familiar with it.

```
describe "adder" do
 it "adds one to the value returned by the default block" do
  adder do
    5
  end.should == 6
 end

 it "adds 3 to the value returned by the default block" do
   adder(3) do
    5
  end.should == 8
 end
end
```

I tried

```
    def adder
       yield  {|n| return n+1 }
    end
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also, what is `adder`?

Comment: @sawa OP is trying to do sum using block...

Comment: the name of the function rspec is looking for

Comment: @ArupRakshit At the time I posted the comment, the OP had `def add(n) ...`. The OP silently changed the question since then.

Comment: simple questions don't need to be downvoted, could try to be more welcoming to new users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do:

```
def adder(a=1, &block)
  a + yield
end
 => :adder 

adder do
  5
end
 => 6 

adder(3) do
  5
end
 => 8
```

You need to learn [how to pass a block as parameter](http://mudge.name/2011/01/26/passing-blocks-in-ruby-without-block.html) and [default values for methods](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls#Default_Values)